# How to create the Receiver for launch application in android

Tags: android, android-intent, launching-application

I want to enforce enterprise security by restricting the use of some applications like youtube or gtalk.

My service runs in the background and it should show the home screen on launch of any of the blacklisted applications.

However, there is no intent for Activity/application launch.

Please let me know how to do this.

I have tried this :

```
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(3);

    ComponentName componentInfo = tasks.get(0).topActivity;
    String pkgName = componentInfo.getPackageName();
    if (pkgName.contains("com.google.android.youtube")){

        activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(pkgName);
        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        homeIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(homeIntent);

    }
```